# How to validate a signature signed with PKCS8 private key?

Tags: public-key, pkcs#8

I'm developing a program with Go language for validating signatures.

It receives parameters(public key, signature, plaintext)
and the signature is signed by user's private key in PKCS#8.

I tried to use the function VerifyPKCS1v15 in the package x509
but it didn't work for me.
I guess it may due to the function is oriented for signatures made by pkcs1 private keys.

can anybody help me?
I wanna know if there is any way to validate signatures using pkcs8 public key?

this is my code

func main() {
    var plainTest    = "P0000000025300000100000000001000026720180705140842"
    var hashVal      = "15b47c1d79b0be2aae36a05bcd8644af7bfe3dd4e0c23e2b78692fc900998fca"
    var signatureStr = "WWFCZsD3BhakkCaLAcTPxMvd3Pom1Glhgcc+xhR7tIDBLvkVk/LtxV+2nHw6b9u0Dcla8U4vUR7KH8zpUS7fNJD9yPDDWxH5PYiw4jQTjziiLHSUpuaGbf8N1Y2jKPXvzq1ZFaEAqCirLSmt5KyD3gQ22ysHgYA2vH44zzBApcxYXVbzLbCIGAR5aL/mvYt7uWsh4FX8dQ49v9SqIm/rRBGEbsscF4HpQApy8VqRGvq6EbwrPCfMcpwIbBHdDUR0mneaNg9GH4hozfMC08SZtAMGDk8J/NQway1FisrjpUeZfMe/hANDH1LmfrbThKDgB7WIpDryCXMTsBKjrqyArQ=="
    var pubKeyStr    = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA17hWIujBfiqrd4o0JCEn6N1mzv94VM9LiVHoldvPRDEwCXbeoSebzZElvhkJsPl08o68g1BgRC4LpaGQDcVzwyFMs4DnXEDLapZQpTzkmXaSIYIRYER/U1OgdW5Cq2do/eTrylWdloqWuz5JL2vIr4GFycnEduYVSzFmAqucCvgGEFUxwFxtZ95BVsxfKOt7eFCJWoS0iR2/If5EMG9F6KG6DtDUWg6awN2mIbhm8fqxSF48ehCkPCN4s4YkcUlkmGYEetdBCxbaUh9/S960XjQBK3MXbLIJLgRLoEAdWJ2v6IjaEsw7dQAaMti3QOPr0x7TyHlS7rz/lyjlJjaXEQIDAQAB"

```
publicKeyBase64, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(pubKeyStr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("base64 error : " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("publicKeyBase64: ")
fmt.Println(string(publicKeyBase64))

pub, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(publicKeyBase64)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("failed to parse DER encoded public key: " + err.Error())
}

switch pub := pub.(type) {
case *rsa.PublicKey:
    fmt.Println("pub is of type RSA:", pub)
case *dsa.PublicKey:
    fmt.Println("pub is of type DSA:", pub)
case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
    fmt.Println("pub is of type ECDSA:", pub)
default:
    panic("unknown type of public key")
}

publicKey, isRSAPublicKey := pub.(*rsa.PublicKey)
if !isRSAPublicKey {
    fmt.Println("Public key parsed is not an RSA public key")
}

signatureBytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(signatureStr)
fmt.Println("signatureBytes : " + string(signatureBytes))

validateBytes := sha256.Sum256([]byte(plainTest))
fmt.Println("validateBytes : " + string(validateBytes[:]))

err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(publicKey, crypto.SHA256, validateBytes[:], signatureBytes)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("ok")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, it turns out my publicKey is wrong.
I mean not the format, but the key is not paired with the private key.
I change to another pair of key, and the code worked.